# Module PyQt5 import issue

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyqt5

I got this error on PyCharm

> Traceback (most recent call last)
>       from import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

this is the import statement

> from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

Although that I have checked the library in terminal using pip3 command and it works. 
Also, I have configured manually the interrupter to be with python3 but still the error not resolved. Any idea of solving this issue?

Comment: Can you give details on your "check". From your pycharm console, `import sys; print(sys.path)` should help you with that.

Comment: So is this the same python3 as the one where PyQt is working outside of pycharm? And do you see your PyQt files within these directories?

Comment: Issue solved by installing package manually.. thank you